# Load API JSON data into SyncFusion Shedule in ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs, api, yii2, syncfusion

I am using [SyncFusion Schedule](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/getting-started/) in this project.
I want to get some data from my API endpoint and load it into my schedule.

[API endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAe9r.png)

The problem is that I need a custom adaptor to tell the schedule how to get the data and I don't know how to create one..

I saw a couple of examples but I still can't put the custom adaptor working. The worst part of this is that I dont know how to manipulate the data to put in the Schedule.

[My Schedule Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Vkx.png)

If you have some suggestion to solve the problem, any alternative to make this in a easier way or other library for schedule let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the info as required by the frontend? You can modify the structure of the data to be returned by reinmplementing the [fields](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait#fields()-detail) method in the model or directly on the controller before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion Support.

We have validated your requirement at our side and prepared a sample with a custom adaptor based on your requirement by making use of the below code snippet.

Code snippet:

```
class CustomAdaptor extends ODataV4Adaptor {
  processResponse() {
    let i = 0;
    // calling base class processResponse function
    let original = super.processResponse.apply(this, arguments);
    // adding event id
    original.forEach((item) => item['EventID'] = ++i);
    return original;
  }
}


this.dataManager = new DataManager({
  url: 'https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/ejservices/api/Schedule/LoadData',
  adaptor: new CustomAdaptor
});
this.dataQuery = new Query().from("Events");
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-custom-adaptor-sample?file=index.js
UG: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/data-binding/#using-custom-adaptor

Kindly refer to the above sample and UG, let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: The problem here is my API, I think. The adaptor can't read the data. Is it because of my XML formatting? Do I need more fields in XML?